# HIbernate - Spring boot / Null references FK when posting an User

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

Controller

```
    @PostMapping
    public User newUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.save(user);
    }
```

ROL ENTITY

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long role_id;
    @Column(name = "rol")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleType role;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Permission.class)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "permisos",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")
    )
    private List<Permission> permissions;
```

Entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity= com.ecommerce.model.Role.class)
    private Role role;
```

POST EXAMPLE

```
{
    "name" : "User",
    "password" : "1111",
    "role_id": 1
}
```

User have a relathionship with Roles, i have a Rol added to sql, but return NULL when i posted, this is what i expected!
I cant find the solution
Query example :

insert into usuarios (name,password,role_id) values ("Ignacio","1234",1);

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT
{
"id": 14,
"name": "User",
"password": "1111",
"role": {
"role_id": 1,
"role": "seller",
"permissions": [
"add_product"
     ]
  }
}
```

```
OUTPUT
{
"id": 15,
"name": "User2",
"password": "1111",
"role": null
}
```

Comment: So the user is correctly added to DB with a role id? And the returned user does not have a role object set?

Comment: the user is correctly added to DB but with role = "NULL"

{
"id": 15,
"name": "User2",
"password": "1111",
"role": null
},

Comment: Reason being that you only pass the role id, but not the actual role object to the request. What you need to do is fetch the role from DB, then call `user.setRole(roleFromDB);` and only then you call `userService.save(user)`

Comment: How i fetch the role from DB ? yes i understand my idea was, passing id_role and then hibernate populate with the rol, its not possible ?
If i post the complete rol work well

Comment: hibernate does not automatically fetch the role by ID for you, that you have to do manually. You probably have a `RoleService` which you can use to call find the correct role. Also, how are you converting the POST example to a user object? unless you have an additional field `role_id`, the role will already be `null` before you even call the insert

Comment: I dont have a RoleService yet but i understand what you are saying my doubt is how i posted ? i always have to send the complete rol ? the only solution i found was @JsonProperty role_id to the class and works, but i dont know if it is a good solution. What dou you mean how im converting the object ?      PostMapping
    public User newUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.save(user);
    }

Comment: At some point, the POST request creates a `User` object. At that point you need to check if the field `private Role role;` is also set (I assume it is not). As you are not showing a field that is named `role_id`, I assume that it doesn't exist yet. Thus you need to add it to your `User` class. Then in `public User newUser(@RequestBody User user)` method you need to fetch the role based on the ID you passed and set it to the user. After that you can save the user

Comment: I understand Do you have an example of how to do it the fetch? hibernate try to do this
Hibernate: insert into usuarios (name, password, role_id) values (?, ?, ?), if i add this to the class User    
 @JsonProperty("role_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("role_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Long role_id;

the post work fine and show the role created manually in workbench

Comment: Add `@Transient` to `private Long role_id;`, otherwise hibernate wants to insert it as well. For fetching you need a `RoleService`/`RoleDao`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution then with a DTO is more cleaner. Add one more property Long role_id and ignore property. When you do a post hibernate try to insert an id not a object. This way the db stay the same, but this new property is what hibernate use to catch the relationship. I hope this help.

Then with a DTO you can change the way that the info is showing in the get

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id",nullable = true,insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity= com.ecommerce.model.Role.class)
    private Role role;

    @JsonProperty("role_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("role_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Long role_id;
```

POST EXAMPLE NOW

```
{
    "name" : "Federico",
    "password" : "tupassword",
    "role_id": 1
}
```

OUTPUT

```
{
"id": 14,
"name": "Federico",
"password": "tupassword",
"role": {
"role_id": 1,
"role": "seller",
"permissions": [
"add_product",
"edit_product",
"delete_product"
        ]
   }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).